# AT&T assembler substring

Tags: assembly, x86, att

Say I have a string "Hello to everyone" in register %edx, and I want to move "Hello to e" to %eax, is this possible? And how? (Address to the string is in 12(%ebp)).

Comment: No it's not possible. You don't have the string in `edx` you have a pointer to it. And it won't magically get shorter unless you terminate it (possibly after copying).

Comment: Ok, so what you're saying, is that if I have a certain index I want to go to (in this case say 10), then I can and that byte with 0x0 to zero it out, and thus be able to shorten it? The byte I zero out would be lost, but that's fine.

Comment: Yes, if you poke a zero byte into the middle of the string that will effectively truncate it. Make sure it is writable though.

Answer (score 1):

> "Hello to everyone" in register %edx

You don't actually "have" the string in a register. Instead, you have memory reference to it.

If you do not want to truncate the original string. You can do this

```
; Method #1: Copy the cut part of the string to a new address %edi
movl $10,%ecx   ; Store the length of cut string to %ecx
movl %edx,%esi  ; Copy the address of original string to %esi (Source Index)
rep movsb       ; This instruction copies %ecx bytes from %esi to %edi (Destination Index)
movb $0,(%edi)
movl %edi,%eax
```

Use method #2 if you only want to modify the current string

```
; Method #2: Cut the current string
movb $0,10(%edx) ; Put a null-terminator at the end of letter 'e'
```

Comment: Your first snippet doesn't terminate the copied string, and `mov %edi,%eax` *after* `rep movsb` gives you a pointer to the end of the copy.  Your 2nd version should probably use `movb` to only store one terminating `0` byte.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oops. My AT&T Assembly is not as good as Intel one